# Reshape dataframe in R, different dates

Tags: r, date, reshape, transpose

I have data that looks like this:

| ID | Name | Role | Status | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | GM | Current | 12.04.2021 |
| 1 | Ann | GM | Previous | 10.07.2020 |
| 1 | Mary | GM | Previous | 24.01.2017 |
| 2 | Ann | GM | Current | 12.04.2021 |
| 2 | Josef | GM | Previous | 02.07.2015 |
| 3 | Sophie | GM | Current | 12.04.2021 |
| 4 | Ben | GM | Current | 12.04.2021 |
| 4 | Lucas | GM | Previous | 30.07.2018 |
| 4 | Peter | GM | Previous | 18.04.2017 |
| 4 | Susan | GM | Previous | 16.09.2015 |

The ID is unique for each "business". First of all, I want to have 1 row for each ID, and then each date needs to generate a new column. The first date in each ID has to be in "Date1", second "Date2", etc. It's worth mentioning that my dataset can take different numbers of rows for each ID.

I will use this analysis to look at changes in General Managers (GM) for each business, therefore only interested in ID and Date.

My final dataset will look like as the table below:

| ID | Date1 | Date2 | Date3 | Date4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12.04.2021 | 10.07.2020 | 24.01.2017 | NA |
| 2 | 12.04.2021 | 02.07.2015 | NA | NA |
| 3 | 12.04.2021 | NA | NA | NA |
| 4 | 12.04.2021 | 30.07.2018 | 18.04.2017 | 16.09.2015 |

I have tried to search for previous cases with reshape in R studio, but have not found similar to mine. Can someone help me? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please paste your sample data as an object into the question: use `doput(your_dataframe) this will make the question reproducible and allow testing of solutions. This link may help  [MRE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a tidyverse solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2),
  Name = c("John", "Ann", "Mary", "Ann", "Joseph"),
  Role = rep("GM", 5),
  Status = c("Current", "Previous", "Previous", "Current", "Previous"),
  Date = c("12.04.2021", "10.07.2020", "24.01.2017", "12.04.2021", "02.07.2015")
)

df

  ID   Name Role   Status       Date
1  1   John   GM  Current 12.04.2021
2  1    Ann   GM Previous 10.07.2020
3  1   Mary   GM Previous 24.01.2017
4  2    Ann   GM  Current 12.04.2021
5  2 Joseph   GM Previous 02.07.2015


dfnew <- df %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(ID) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(rownum = row_number()) %>% 
  dplyr::select(ID, rownum, Date) %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = rownum, values_from = Date, names_glue = "Date{rownum}")

dfnew

# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   ID [2]
     ID Date1      Date2      Date3     
  <dbl> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     
1     1 12.04.2021 10.07.2020 24.01.2017
2     2 12.04.2021 02.07.2015 NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)

DT <- fread("ID     Name    Role    Status  Date
1   John    GM  Current     12.04.2021
1   Ann     GM  Previous    10.07.2020
1   Mary    GM  Previous    24.01.2017
2   Ann     GM  Current     12.04.2021
2   Josef   GM  Previous    02.07.2015
3   Sophie  GM  Current     12.04.2021
4   Ben     GM  Current     12.04.2021
4   Lucas   GM  Previous    30.07.2018
4   Peter   GM  Previous    18.04.2017
4   Susan   GM  Previous    16.09.2015")

# summarise dates by id
ans <- DT[, .(dates = paste0(Date, collapse = "#")), by = ID]
# now split
ans[, paste0("Date", 1:length(tstrsplit(ans$dates, "#"))) := 
      tstrsplit( dates, "#")][, dates := NULL][]

#    ID      Date1      Date2      Date3      Date4
# 1:  1 12.04.2021 10.07.2020 24.01.2017       <NA>
# 2:  2 12.04.2021 02.07.2015       <NA>       <NA>
# 3:  3 12.04.2021       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
# 4:  4 12.04.2021 30.07.2018 18.04.2017 16.09.2015
```

Comment: Thank you, @Wimpel ! This is what I want. It is possible to do this in a dataframe. Alternatively, change from dataframe to a data table?

Comment: setDT() changes a data.frame to a data.table. setDF() vice versa.